# Existence of a tuple

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

There is a polynomial of the form $P(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are distinct integers. Let $P(x)=p_0+p_1x+...+p_5x^5$. Find any tuple $(a,b,c,d,e)$ such that cardinality of the set ${i:p_i=0}$ is maximum. How to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: This problem is wrong since $p_5=1$, so $P_5$ is empty  set.

Comment: @aqua I edited!

Comment: What you edit is not the issue. It is $p_5$. In first expresion it is 1, so it can never be 0.

Comment: @Aqua all that means is that the maximal number is $<5$...but that does not make the problem wrong.

Comment: Well they could write it correctly. I doubt they actually know what are they asking. @lulu

Comment: @Aqua I don't see the ambiguity....For every suitable quintuple $(a,b,c,d,e)$ we can compute the number of indices $i$ for which $p_i=0$ and we seek to maximize that number.  If we could take $(0,0,0,0,0)$, we'd have $5$ such $i$ but that's not an eligible quintuple. (note: earlier I said the max was $<5$ but I should have said $<6$). If we take, say $(1,-1,2,-2,0)$ we get two $i$ for which $p_i=0$.  Is that a maximal example?  I haven't been able to make $3$ vanish but perhaps it is possible.  Anyway, that's the problem.

Comment: Note:  I keep making the same silly off-by-one error.  $x(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)$ has $3$ $i$ for which $p_i$ is $0$.  that is optimal...I'll post an explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quintuple $(1,-1,2,-2,0)$ gives us $$p(x)=x^5-5x^3+4x$$

For which $3$ terms vanish.

To see that this is optimal:

Method I:

Descartes' [Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) tells us that the number of positive roots can not exceed the number of sign changes (writing the polynomial in the standard way).  Replacing $x$ by $-x$ allows us to consider the negative roots.  Even allowing for a root at $0$ we see that we need $2$ sign changes.  If four of the coefficients vanished this would not be possible.

Method II:

If $4$ terms vanished the polynomial would have to have the form $$p(x)=x^5+Ax=x(x^4+A)$$

for some integer $A$.  But that would imply that the roots were $0$ plus the four complex roots of $A$.  In particular, the roots can not all be distinct integers.

Comment: But $p_3$ and $p_1$ are not zero? As I understand they all have to be zero.

Comment: @Aqua  No...we just seek a suitable quintuple such that the number of vanishing coefficients is maximized.  In theory, you could have $5$ vanishing coefficients...but $(0,0,0,0,0)$ is not eligible (as the OP specified distinct roots).  So then, still in theory, one could have $4$ vanishing coefficients but the rule of signs precludes that.